# Setting frame for UIButton ignored

Tags: ios, uibutton, autolayout

I have an iOS 8 application which is using AutoLayout for some involved views. However, the main view has a lot of programmatically created views which take too long to arrange using Auto Layout. I want to manage the layout of those views myself.

Inside that view are some buttons. When I try to set the frame of the button, it is ignored - the frame remains unchanged after the command, even when stepping through it in the debugger. I've set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to true and false, no difference (for this particular problem), and I've deleted all constraints on this button and the view above it (both before execution and in code just before doing layout, in desperation).

Comment: Add constraints for the width/height to the buttons and for leading and trailing in their container view and change the constraint values in the code. You want translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints set to OFF for the containing view in the storyboard or your buttons will all have constraints created for them which will be why you can not move them just by changing the frame.

Answer (score 0):

Creating & managing constraints programatically is tough to trace. Anyhow , try to use storyboard directly - this is the best way to manage constrants easily.